# Can tools like IDA/OD be used to reverse engineer a dll?

Tags: reverse-engineering

I know they can be used to deal with a binary executable, but what about dll, does it require any additional steps to deal with a dll?

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not require any additional steps to reverse a DLL.  On Windows, a DLL does not differ very much from an EXE, there's just a few different flags and so on.

IDAPro will handle a DLL with no issue.